# how to delete all snapshots corresponding to an AMI using boto

Tags: python, boto, amazon-ami

I'm trying to delete the all snapshots corresponding to an AMI. I've tried the below command. With the following command I'm able to delete only one volume. In Boto delete_snapshot set to True we can delete EBS volume mounted at /dev/sda1. is there any way to delete all volumes for an AMI?

```
>>> conn.deregister_image('ami-xxxx', delete_snapshot=True, dry_run=False)
True
```

After ran the command one snapshot deleted, but one more snapshot still showing up. How can I delete all snapshots for ami-xxxx ?

Comment: the last one is the ami image's snapshot, unless you deregister the ami image, it will be always there.

Comment: @BMW I can delete the snapshot associated with an EBS volume mounted at /dev/sda1 with the following command(deregister_image('ami-xxxx', delete_snapshot=True, dry_run=False)). But I'm unable to delete the volumes associated with /dev/sdf ..etc

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any solution for this question. So I wrote a python script to do this job.

```
    try:
        list_snaps = conn.get_all_snapshots(filters={'owner_id' :'xxxxx'}) #it used to save some time if we filter by owner
        for i in list_snaps:
            find_ami_id = re.search(r'.* for (.*) from .*', i.description, re.M|re.I)
            if find_ami_id:
                if find_ami_id.group(1) == b: #b is the ami id that we were deleted
                    print "Delete the following snap id: %s" %i.id
                    conn.delete_snapshot(i.id, dry_run=False)
                    time.sleep(10) #wait for a while to delete snapshots one by one
    except boto.exception.BotoServerError, e:
        print e.error_message
```